# How prove that for sufficiently large $n$ the functions $x(t)^{i}y(t)^{j},0\le i,j\le n$ are linearly dependent

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-curves

An algebraic curve in $\mathbb R^2$ is the locus of zero of a polynomial $f(x,y)$ in two variables. By a polynomial path in $\mathbb R^2$ we mean a parametrized path $x=x(t),y=y(t)$, where $x(t),y(t)$ are polynomials in $t$.

> Show that every polynomial path lies on a real algebraic curve by showing that, for sufficiently large $n$, the functions $x(t)^{i}y(t)^{j}$, $0\le i,j\le n$ are linearly dependent.

Thank you someone can help me   solution.

and this problem is my frend ask me, I consider somehours, and I can't solution,and he say this problem from a book(Specific the name of the book didn't tell me)

[image]

Comment: OP, zyx provided a great answer but he takes the computational algebra approach. Since this problem is from a traditional abstract algebra book, what do you think is the author's intended idea for a solution?

Comment: Is this even true actually?

Answer (score 5):

> show that every polynomial path lies on a real algebraic curve

This is called *implicitization*, which is a special case of *Zariski closure*.
Implemented algorithms use Groebner bases, but for polynomial plane curves an 'explicit' answer is to write the curve as Resultant($x - x(t), y - y(t))=0$ with both terms regarded as polynomials in $t$.  An algorithmic answer is to eliminate $t$ from the pair of equations in variables $x,y,t$, to get one equation in $x,y$.

> for sufficiently large $n$,the functions $x(t)^i y(t)^j,0≤i,j≤n$ are linearly dependent.

The number of $(i,j)$ with $\deg (x^i y^j) \leq n$ is approximately $Cn^2$, it is the number of lattice points in a triangle. For large $n$ this number exceeds $n+1$, the maximum number of linearly independent polynomials in $t$ of degree $\leq n$, and there must be a nonzero linear relation.

The problem appears to be from (Michael) Artin's textbook *Algebra*.

Comment: Could you give references?

Comment: Thank you very much,sorry,But I don't understand,can you give me some references withi this problem ?

Comment: Any book on computational algebraic geometry or commutative algebra that talks about Groebner bases and resultants.  Cox-Little-O'Shea is one (I think, "Ideals Varieties Algorithms" is the title).  [@user64494 .]

Comment: oh,Thanks,my frend,+1

Comment: you mean this book?http://www.math.ku.dk/~holm/download/ideals-varieties-and-algorithms.pdf

Comment: Yes.  On page 130 of the PDF file there is the general result for polynomial implicitization.  For two equations defining a plane curve it is just "eliminate $t$".

Comment: I google it,I found this problem is from this PDF:http://www.math.ust.hk/~amoy/math218/oldartinchapterhw03.pdf,But I don't kown  this is from what book,Thank you ?

Comment: You are welcome.  By the way, your translation of problems from the Chinese books and competitions are very interesting to many of the people using the site (thank you for sharing them).  I hope you are not discouraged by the "homework mania" on this web site (the *what did you try* comments). It comes primarily from the North American education system, where the final grades at school are based significantly on homework, and not only examinations.  In most of the world examinations are considered the only fair method and "cheating" by posting homework problems to a web site makes no sense.